# BASH: testing the number of arguments passed in an IF statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, arguments

i'm trying to send two arguments to .run file.
$2 default should be 0.

> if $2 arg = 1 then
>
> ```
> grep -i a -1 --color -E $1 *.*
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
> grep -i --color -E $1 *.*
> ```

,
something like this

```
if [${2:-0} = 1] then
  grep -i a -1 --color -E $1 *.*
else
  grep -i --color -E $1 *.*
fi
```

but it didn't seem to work ? any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question leaves a bit of guess work as to what you are trying to do. You you don't use `$2` anywhere, so you just want to use that as a flag to decide to run grep in a different way? If so, use `$#` will tell you how many arguments were passed. To test if there are two of them, you could use `(( $# = 2 ))`.

As Tom Fenech suggested, you have a syntax errors in your code. There should be a semicolon after the `]` or `then` should be put on a new line. Also, I believe you need spaces after `[` and before `]`. So here's a guess of what you might have been trying to do:

```
if (( $# == 2 ));  then
  grep -i a -1 --color -E $1 *.*
else
  grep -i --color -E $1 *.*
fi
```

Comment: If you want to test for integer equality, you should use `-eq`. For strings, use `=`. `==` is supported by bash but not other shells.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts, that's exactly what i was looking for .
thanks

Comment: @Tom Fenech: point taken. I've changed `[ .. ]`   to `(( .. ))`

Answer (score 2):

Brackets are not just syntax: `[` is actually a **command**, so it requires whitespace to separate it from its arguments:

```
if [ ${2:-0} = 1 ]; then
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test